# Passing rel variable with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

What i am trying to accomplish is to get the variable $meta_value_pass to pass through ajax to another page 186. This Page should pick up the variable, use it in a loop and output send back the resulting html.

source of the call:

```
$meta_value_pass = Entwerfen3;
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

alert ("helloworld");
    $(".sorting").click(function()
{      
var post_value = $meta_value_pass;
jQuery("#projektwrapper")

            .empty()

            .html("<div style='text-align: center; padding: 30px;'>Loading...</div>");


jQuery.ajax({

            url: "http://web318.login-11.hoststar.at/ben/xarch/azall/?page_id=186",
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",
            data: ({player: post_value}),
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery("#projektwrapper").html(data); } 

  });
    });

});
</script>
```

PHP to process the variable and return the html:

```
    <?php

    /*
        Template Name: Projekte Getter
    */


    $meta_value_pass = $_POST['player'];

    $args= array(
    'meta_query' =>  array(
    array(
            'key' => 'cf_cf_Lehrveranstaltung',
            'value' => $meta_value_pass,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ))
            );


   $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

Comment: And, you are unable to get value in php ?

Comment: If it take "Entwerfen3" for the variable $meta_value_pass, i get nothing back at all. But if i change it to $(this).attr('rel'); i get back an answer, that the array is empty.

Comment: Shouldn't you enclose it in <?php echo $meta_value_pass; ?> to pass it to HTML?